# using the "pefile.py" to get file(.exe) version

Tags: python

I want to use python to get the executable file version, and i know of [pefile.py](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/)

how to use it to do this?

notes: the executable file may be not complete.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete example script that does what you want:

```
import sys

def main(pename):
    from pefile import PE
    pe = PE(pename)
    if not 'VS_FIXEDFILEINFO' in pe.__dict__:
        print "ERROR: Oops, %s has no version info. Can't continue." % (pename)
        return
    if not pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO:
        print "ERROR: VS_FIXEDFILEINFO field not set for %s. Can't continue." % (pename)
        return
    verinfo = pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO
    filever = (verinfo.FileVersionMS >> 16, verinfo.FileVersionMS & 0xFFFF, verinfo.FileVersionLS >> 16, verinfo.FileVersionLS & 0xFFFF)
    prodver = (verinfo.ProductVersionMS >> 16, verinfo.ProductVersionMS & 0xFFFF, verinfo.ProductVersionLS >> 16, verinfo.ProductVersionLS & 0xFFFF)
    print "Product version: %d.%d.%d.%d" % prodver
    print "File version: %d.%d.%d.%d" % filever

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.stderr.write("ERROR:\n\tSyntax: verinfo <pefile>\n")
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1]))
```

The relevant lines being:

```
    verinfo = pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO
    filever = (verinfo.FileVersionMS >> 16, verinfo.FileVersionMS & 0xFFFF, verinfo.FileVersionLS >> 16, verinfo.FileVersionLS & 0xFFFF)
    prodver = (verinfo.ProductVersionMS >> 16, verinfo.ProductVersionMS & 0xFFFF, verinfo.ProductVersionLS >> 16, verinfo.ProductVersionLS & 0xFFFF)
```

all of which happens only after checking that we have something meaningful in these properties.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by "executable file version" you mean a) on Windows, b) the information shown in the Properties, Details tab, under "File version", you can retrieve this using the [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) package with a command like the following:

```
>>> import win32api as w
>>> hex(w.GetFileVersionInfo('c:/windows/regedit.exe', '\\')['FileVersionMS'])
'0x60000'
>>> hex(w.GetFileVersionInfo('c:/windows/regedit.exe', '\\')['FileVersionLS'])
'0x17714650'
```

Note that 0x60000 has the major/minor numbers (6.0) and 0x17714650 is the next two, which if taken as two separate words (0x1771 and 0x4650, or 6001 and 18000 in decimal) correspond to the values on my machine, where regedit's version is 6.0.6001.18000.

Comment: Given the module in question is platform-independent, but your answer relies on a Win32-specific module. This is why I decided to downvote the answer.

Comment: 0xC0000022L he mentions pefile.py but it's unclear whether he meant this to be cross-platform. He refers to ".exe" which is generally a Windows thing. Also, I did say "assuming you mean on Windows", so it was clear my answer wasn't meant to be cross-platform. I think your downvote was premature at best (before the OP clarifies) but whatever...

Comment: The module `pefile` itself is cross-platform.

Comment: I fully understand that. My point is that it's unclear whether the OP really understood that, as his inclusion of ".exe" in the question could mean he wanted Windows only. It's simply not clear, yet, unless you can read his mind.

Answer (score 0):

The version numbers of Windows programs are stored in the resource section of the program file, not in the PE format header. I'm not familiar with `pefile.py`, so I don't know whether it directly handles resource sections too. If not, you should be able to find the information you need for that in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx).