# how can I used the “pefile.py” to get file(.exe) version

Tags: python

I want to used python to get the executed file version, and i know the [pefile.py](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/)

how to used it to do this?

notes: the executed file may be not completely.

Comment: This is belong to stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question has now become a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264472/using-the-pefile-py-to-get-file-exe-version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using the "pefile.py" to get file(.exe) version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264472/using-the-pefile-py-to-get-file-exe-version)

Answer (score 7):

This is the best answer I think you can find:

```
import pefile
pe = pefile.PE("/path/to/something.exe")

print hex(pe.VS_VERSIONINFO.Length)
print hex(pe.VS_VERSIONINFO.Type)
print hex(pe.VS_VERSIONINFO.ValueLength)
print hex(pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.Signature)
print hex(pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.FileFlags)
print hex(pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.FileOS)
for fileinfo in pe.FileInfo:
  if fileinfo.Key == 'StringFileInfo':
    for st in fileinfo.StringTable:
      for entry in st.entries.items():
        print '%s: %s' % (entry[0], entry[1])    
  if fileinfo.Key == 'VarFileInfo':
    for var in fileinfo.Var:
      print '%s: %s' % var.entry.items()[0]
```

[From Ero Carrera's (the author of `pefile.py`) own blog](http://blog.dkbza.org/2007/02/pefile-parsing-version-information-from.html)

Comment: I have tried this on an NSIS-Installer binary without success (`fileinfo.StringTable` was not defined). [I came up with a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16076661/274483) using the `pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.ProductVersionMS`,`pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.ProductVersionLS` attributes.

Comment: Note that VS_FIXEDFILEINFO is now a list, so you need to use, e.g., pe.VS_FIXEDFILEINFO[0].ProductVersionMS. Also, see the responses to the original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264472/using-the-pefile-py-to-get-file-exe-version for notes on speed improvements.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that I understand your problem correctly, but if it's something along the lines of using pefile to retrieve the version of a provided executable, then perhaps (taken from [the tutorial][1])

```
import pefile
pe = pefile.PE("/path/to/pefile.exe")
print pe.dump_info()
```

will provide you with the version information. I have no idea how sensible pefile is when parsing incomplete files, but conjecturing that the version information is somewhere in the header and that pefile uses a generator to read the file, then it should be possible to read the information if the header is parseable.